# awk how to exclude N first and X last lines and print second column?

Tags: bash, awk

This is the text:

```
line1 data1
line2 data2
line3 data3
line4 data4
line5 data5
line6 data6
line7 data7
```

I want to exclude the first three lines AND the one last line and then print the second column.

This is the expected output:

```
line4 data4
line5 data5
line6 data6
```

So far I learnt this:

```
awk 'FNR>=4 {print $2}' file
```

I googled and this is which excludes one line from the last:

```
awk 'NR>n{print A[NR%n]} {A[NR%n]=$0}' n=1 file
```

But instead of this as an example, are there better (and maybe easier to memorize and learn)  ways instead of this?

```
awk 'FNR>=4 {print $2}' file | awk 'NR>n{print A[NR%n]} {A[NR%n]=$0}' n=1
```

Comment: _and then print the second column_, but then you print both first and second column...

Comment: Just to clarify: So in your case, N is 3 and X is 1, correct? In this case, why are you using `awk` instead of `tail` and `head`?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix your specification _I want to ... and then print the **second** column_ or your expected output where both columns are printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`, to skip the `n` first lines and the `x` last lines you can use a `x`-elements array (`arr`) as a circular buffer, start printing only at line `n+x+1`, print the oldest element in the array, and replace it with the second field of the current line. Adapt the values of `n` and `x` to your needs.

```
$ awk -v n=3 -v x=1 '{i=NR%x+1} NR>n+x {print arr[i]} {arr[i]=$2}' file
data4
data5
data6
```

Answer (score 3):

Addressing your memorizability / readability concerns, also consider handing over the selection to other tools, and have `awk` just do the projection. For example, `tail` could start the input stream with the `4`th line, and `head` could stop it with `1` line remaining:

```bash
< input.txt tail -n+4 | head -n-1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Or preprocess with `head` only, as `awk` can handle the omissions at the beginning quite readably:

```bash
< input.txt head -n-1 | awk 'NR>3 {print $2}'
```

Output:

```
data4
data5
data6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```bash
$ awk 'FNR>4 {print last} {last=$2}' file
data4
data5
data6
```

when `FNR` is greater than `4`, it prints the value of `last` (which corresponds to the second field of the previous line).

Comment: Can I ask, how would you modify this to exclude the X last lines? because this currently seems that it would only exclude the last line

Comment: @experimentunit1998X see https://askubuntu.com/questions/475694/awk-command-to-print-all-the-lines-except-the-last-three-lines

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the easiest to remember would be:

```
$ awk -v n=3 -v x=1 '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=n+1; i<=(NR-x); i++) { $0=a[i]; print $2 } }' file
data4
data5
data6
```

but that does require you to store NR lines in memory. Alternatively read the input twice:

```
$ awk -v n=3 -v x=1 'NR==FNR{e=NR-x+1} (n<FNR) && (FNR<e){ print $2 }' file file
data4
data5
data6
```

but of course that wouldn't work with input from a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

in my method, it first stores all the lines starting from the fourth line (excluding the first three) in an array called `line` and then, at the end of the file (`END`), it loops through the array and prints the second column of each line:

```
awk 'NR > 3 {line[NR]=$0} END {for (i=4; i<NR; i++) print line[i]}' file | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output :

```
data4
data5
data6
```

Comment: Thanks, but suppose I don't know the number of lines is 7. I generate this file from another command and it gives me a file with an unknown number of lines to me

Answer (score 1):

Count the lines and save it into a variable, eg.:

```
<infile awk 'NR > n && NR < N-x+1 { print $2 }' N=$(wc -l < infile) n=3 x=1
```